# Simplifying nested-lists as a Cartesian product

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

I have a nested list in Python as:

```
lst = ['alpha', ['beta', 'gamma'], ['delta', 'peta', 'lambda']]
```

I need a function that will return a list having the Cartesian product of them. Well, I think Cartesian product is not a right word, but still in a logical way the result will look like:

```
final_lst = your_magical_function(lst)
print final_lst

'''
[['alpha','beta','delta'],
['alpha','beta','peta'],
['alpha','beta','lambda'],
['alpha','gamma','delta'],
['alpha','gamma','peta']
['alpha','gamma','lambda']]
'''
```

A function with recursion or without, both are welcomed.

Comment: Why do you have to use recursion?

Comment: It's okay, I dont really need a recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), which will require you to slightly modify your input (`'alpha'` to `['alpha']`):

```
from itertools import product

lst = [['alpha'],['beta','gamma'],['delta','peta','lambda']]

for res in product(*lst):
    print(res)

>> ('alpha', 'beta', 'delta')

('alpha', 'beta', 'peta')
('alpha', 'beta', 'lambda')
('alpha', 'gamma', 'delta')
('alpha', 'gamma', 'peta')
('alpha', 'gamma', 'lambda')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) once you've converted all the items to lists:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> lst = ['alpha',['beta','gamma'],['delta','peta','lambda']]
>>> list(product(*(x if isinstance(x, list) else [x] for x in lst)))
[('alpha', 'beta', 'delta'), ('alpha', 'beta', 'peta'), ('alpha', 'beta', 'lambda'), ('alpha', 'gamma', 'delta'), ('alpha', 'gamma', 'peta'), ('alpha', 'gamma', 'lambda')]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is great to use libraries in Python! However, if you are looking for a pure Python implementation:

```
def CartesianProduct(list_entry):
# Save Sizes of Everything
size_dictionary = {}

# Get Size of Entire Entry List
size_dictionary["full_size"] = len(list_entry)

# Get Sizes of All Sub Entries
for i in range(len(list_entry)):
    if not (isinstance(list_entry[i],list)):
        list_entry[i] = [list_entry[i]]
    size_dictionary[i] = len(list_entry[i])

# Now lets create the cartesian product
# Lets Create a Dictionary to hold all of the results
cartesian_result = {}

# Lets get the size of the final result
final_result_amount = 1
for i in range(size_dictionary["full_size"]):
    final_result_amount = final_result_amount * size_dictionary[i]

# And create the final results
for i in range(final_result_amount):
    cartesian_result[i] = []

    for j in range(size_dictionary["full_size"]):
        cartesian_result[i].append(list_entry[j][i % size_dictionary[j]])

    print(cartesian_result[i])

def main():
    lst = ['alpha',['beta','gamma'],['delta','peta','lambda']]
    CartesianProduct(lst)

main()
```

It is not nearly as pretty and simple as using itertools, but nonetheless it is fun to implement the logic that the libraries use once in awhile.